# Which astronauts or cosmonauts were injured by a hard landing?

Tags: landing, astronauts, medical, capsule

[Sigmund Jähn](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmund_J%C3%A4hn), the first German in orbit, was injured during a hard landing of the [Soyuz 29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_7K-T) capsule on September 3rd, 1978. He got permanent damages of his vertebral column.

Are there other astronauts who were injured by a hard landing or a hard reentry?

Comment: We may never know.

Comment: Certainly the Space Shuttle Challenger disaster would count as a "hard landing".  I don't know whether you'd count the Columbia disaster as a "hard landing" or not, since the craft broke apart on reentry.

Answer (score 25):

[Apollo 12, Alan Bean.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_12#Splashdown) The capsule hit a rising wave, and the impact force knocked a camera out of a bracket, which hit Bean in the head and briefly knocked him out. He suffered a mild concussion and needed six stitches, but had no permanent injury.

Comment: Alan Bean's injury was also mentioned in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25473/26446) to a different question.

Comment: @DrSheldon An exceptionally well-written answer!

Answer (score 23):

Boris Volynov broken several teeth during hard landing of the [Soyuz-5 mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_5).

Answer (score 17):

American cosmonaut [Donald Pettit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Pettit) injured his shoulder when the [Soyuz TMA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_TMA-1) had to fall back to a ballistic reentry following a capsule malfunction. The hard landing was further complicated by the parachute dragging the capsule along the ground after landing. Pettit was immediately moved from the landing site by a rescue helicopter.

Answer (score 14):

The female South Korean astronaut Yi So-yeon may have been injured in [Soyuz TMA-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_TMA-11#Ballistic_reentry) on April 19, 2008.

> Yi So-yeon was hospitalized after her return to South Korea due to
> injuries caused by the rough return voyage in the Soyuz TMA-11
> spacecraft. The South Korean Science Ministry stated that the
> astronaut had a minor injury to her neck muscles and had bruised her
> spinal column.

> Due to a malfunction with the Soyuz vehicle, the craft followed a
> ballistic re-entry which subjects the crew to severe gravitational
> forces up to 10 times the amount experienced on Earth.
>
> Yi was hospitalized after her return to Korea due to severe back
> pains. Though many believed these pains were the result of the
> rough landing, they were in fact normal and expected. They were the
> result of spinal re-compression.

Quotes from Wikipedia articles about [Soyuz TMA-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_TMA-11#Ballistic_reentry) and [Yi So-yeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yi_So-yeon#Post-flight).

So the back pain may have been caused by either the reentry or by the prior stay in weightlessness.

Comment: I don't believe their gender is all that related to the question, their injury was due to spinal damage.

Answer (score 13):

During the abort of [Soyuz 7K-T No.39](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_7K-T_No.39) launch, [Vasily Lazarev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Lazarev) was injured by very high g-loads ( up to 21.3 g, 15 g were expected) and was never able to fly to space again. It was April 5, 1975.

Comment: That wasn't the landing.

Comment: @RussellBorogove When I wrote the question, I did not know a reentry could be that hard causing injuries, so I did not ask for. But I think answers about hard reentries are interesting here too.