# What is BECO? (Gemini) Same as MECO?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, history, terminology, project-gemini

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27318/12102) links to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/7857/12102) which shows the acceleration g-force envelopes experienced by early astronauts, reaching as high as almost **7.5g!**

Both show BECO, which is what I might call MECO or Main Engine Cut-Off if I am understanding correctly.

Is BECO the same as MECO? Does it stand for *Big* Engine Cut-Off?

After getting beaten up [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27204/12102) for not pre-Googling, I can testify that I have indeed searched for "Gemini BECO" and all I get is a [baby carrier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7skU.jpg).

[image]

[image]

Comment: The trick is to make the search more specific. "Gemini launch BECO" gives an NTRS link as one of the top 10 results.

Comment: @Hobbes there's no reason to expect google results for different people and/or different locations will be the same or even similar. Here are my first two pages for example: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuOh3.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqIw2.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOOgN.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wljvm.png) It picked up this SE question and a Wikipedia article, but no NTRS link. I am sure I could have found something had I spent long enough though.

Comment: Adding extra terms oftentimes works -- except when it doesn't. Hobbes' suggestion didn't work for me, which is weird. Google should know by my searches that I don't have young children. Perhaps it "thinks" (it's intelligence is artificial) that I might have grandkids? Even with launch inserted, I had to go to the second page to find a reference. On the other hand, searching for "BECO acronym" worked immediately. (Worked for me, that is. Google customizes its searches to the person (machine) doing to search.)

Comment: I used https://duckduckgo.com/ instead of Google. But the general advice of more specific searches stands.

Comment: OTOH, searching for "BECO site:stackexchange.com" puts this question at the very top (at least for me), and even people looking for "Dr Beco" or for a baby product will see this question with that search criteria.

Comment: Nearly 8 Gs - ouch!

Comment: @Sean yes indeed. The links go back to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27318/12102) and then to [Launch Accelerations: Values, history](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/7829/12102) and answers there. Quite a ride. Now I understand why a lot of the early photos of the space program included those [rotating centrifuges that went up to 20 g!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-G_training)  See also [How fast to they spin astronauts these days? Maximum routine g-training for astronauts in the 21st century?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33518/12102)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

“Booster Engine Cut Off” (though I like Big Engine better)

There’s a handy [NASA Glossary](https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/facts/acronyms.html) for things like this.

Comment: And to fend off the inevitable follow-up,SECO is Sustainer Engine Cut Off.

Comment: More engine cut-off acronyms in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27429/12102).